# Export Crystal report to TTX

Tags: crystal-reports, export, report

I have added a new varchar field(for eg: data appears to be like this 763268953286) in the existing report.  But when I tried to export Crystal report XI data to TTX format,  the similar data comes as 7.63245E + 11. Data format changing when covert to TTX.  In crystal report,  I have formatted the datafield as toText({data fieldname}). How can I format it properly to avoid invalid characters printing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `ToText({Numerical Database Field},2," ",",")`

The argument you need is a Number or Currency value to be converted into a text string; it can be a whole or fractional value.

[Full SAP Article here](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1619352)